# C: fread returning 0

Tags: c, file, pointers, fwrite, fread

)
I am having a problem with fread, and have spent 2 days trying to figure out what's wrong with this. The problem is one of my freads is returning 0..when it shouldn't.

I have a struct such as

```
typedef struct
{
    contents
} tM;
```

I have a pointer of type tM:

```
tM *macs = NULL;
```

that pointer is dynamically allocated with realloc. It stores contents about machines, such as `macs[1].machineName = blabla`. Each time I "add a machine" with realloc, I increase the machineCounter.

I have a function which saves this to a file, and one which reads from it. I don't know which one is malfunctioning, but something's wrong.

I save this to a file this way:

```
void writeMac(int countMac, tM *macs)
{
    FILE *fileMacs;
    if (countMac != 0)
    {
        fileMacs = fopen("machines.dat","wb");
        if (fileMacs == NULL)
        {
            errorcodehere
        }
        else
        {
            fwrite(&countMac,sizeof(int),1,fileMacs);
            fwrite(macs,sizeof(tM),countMac,fileMacs);
            fclose(fileMacs);
        }
    }
}
```

And the file is created with a size other than 0, but I don't know if that is reason enough for me to believe the file is created properly.

And reading from that file:

```
void readMacs(int *countMac, tM *macs)
{
    FILE *fileMacs;
    int numberMachinesRead;
    fileMacs = fopen("machines.dat","rb");
    if (fileMacs == NULL)
    {
        errorcontenthere
    }
    else
    {
        fread(&(*countMac),sizeof(int),1,fileMacs);
        numberMachinesRead = fread(macs, sizeof(tM), *countMac, fileMacs);
        fclose(fileMacs);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when debugging the code, while reading, the first fread does assign to *countMac the correct ammount of machines, however, the 2nd fread returns 0 always.
Even though *countMac > 0, it's returning 0.
What's wrong? Should fread be done differently considering macs is a pointer?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: "*I don't know if that is reason enough for me to believe the file is created properly*" - Why don't you just look at the file?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - he has no idea where it is.

Comment: How is `macs` initialized before it's passed to `readMacs`?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Hi! It's a binary file, I can't open it with notepad and simply find the contents.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz as I posted, the pointer is initialized in the main function in such way: tM *macs = NULL;

Comment: @1337patchy: Google for "hex editor"; this will allow you to inspect binary files.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth will check that tomorrow, but guys can you tell me if fread and fwrite are correct knowing i'm writing/reading a pointer?

Comment: What value does the 2nd `fwrite` return?

Comment: @1337patch Well then it definitely won't work. How could passing `NULL` to `fread` possibly work?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm not passing NULL to fread, I initialize the pointer as NULL but during the program I allocate memory to it and write things to it. I stated that in the first post :/

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I totally forgot I could check the write process that way... Anyways it's writing properly because I tried writing now with 1 machine and it returned 1.

Comment: Also guys, I have just noticed that if I read from the files after writing, without closing the program, it will return the correct number of read things (the fread). however if I close the program and then attempt to read the file, it returns 0.

Comment: @1337patchy Okay, so what does it contain when you call `readMacs`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz never mind. I'm stupid. Already figured out why this was happening. After closing the program I free the memory, and when I read from the file I don't use realloc, fixed that. but now the information being read is all weird...*sigh* Instead of actually reading proper information.

Comment: @1337patchy Post you own answer and accept it.  Saves others time to know this post is answered.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz done sorry!

Comment: @1337patchy  Good that you posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Already figured out why this was happening. After closing the program I free the memory, and when I read from the file I don't use realloc, fixed that